# MySQL wont update db data with php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I cant see the problem in my update form, but no matter what i do it will not update my db.
I was hoping someone in here could help me out.

I have tried to use mysql_error() after the update statement but no errors was found and have tried echoing out the update statement and couldn't see any problems.

URL = http://localhost/maga/php/update_red.php?id=6&read=14

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$pass="*****";
$user="my_db_user";
$db="my_db_name";
$tblname="artikler";

$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db)or die(mysql_error());

$read=(int)$_GET['read'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$read++;

mysql_query("UPDATE $tblname SET read='$read' WHERE id='$id'");
```

?>

Comment: I hope that is not your real db login data you are posting.

Comment: its a closed server so you cant use the data to anything ;)

Comment: Probably is, but it's localhost, we don't know his IP so it's fine.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection by not cleansing your `$id` variable.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: the problem is that im not getting any error, and the db doesn't update

Answer (score 2):

`read` is a [reserved word,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and so needs to be specially quoted with backticks for it to work in query

so try

```
if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $tblname SET `read`='$read' WHERE id='$id'"))
{
    die("update failed with error ".mysql_error());
}
```

Also, the $id value isn't being sanitized in any way, so the code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. Definitely worth your time learning about such things.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting your query:

```
print("UPDATE $tblname SET read='$read' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Also, is your ID field a number? If so, get rid of the quotes you have around it.

Answer (score 0):

do a very simple thing, `echo "UPDATE $tblname SET read='$read' WHERE id='$id'";` 

Try running the query from phpmyadmin or whatever tool you use for writing mysql queries.

See if it gives you any error...

Comment: found the problem, i think 'read' is an sql value because when i change the name of the column i had no problems in updating it. but thanks for the great advises...

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the database connection on your mysql_query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $tblname SET read='".$read."' WHERE id='".$id."'", $con);
```

Comment: You don't have to with mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$pass="*****";
$user="my_db_user";
$db="my_db_name";
$tblname="artikler";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db)or die(mysql_error());

$read=(int)$_GET['read'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$read++;

mysql_query("UPDATE $tblname SET read='$read' WHERE id='$id'");

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\\In your script add the below line and try whether its working
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db,$con)or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, i think 'read' is an sql value because when i changed the name of the column i had no problems in updating it... but thanks for all the good advises...

Comment: that's the answer I gave you yesterday :)